# Magento 2 SKU not showing on Product Page

Tags: magento2

Magento 2 SKU not showing on Product Page any one have experienced about this issue i'm using custom theme.

Comment: try to switch to the default theme, if you see the SKU on product page that mean your custom theme not display the SKU for the product and you need to override your theme and modify it

Comment: yes i have the same issue.. luma theme worked fine.. but i'm using AMSport Magento 2.1.6 version..  is their any advice to override it.

Answer (score 2):

Open file **catalog_product_view.xml** whci can be found in below directory of your theme : `Magento-Catalog\view\frontend\layout\` and find below code block :

`<referenceBlock name="product.info.sku" remove="true"/>`

if you find that code block replace `remove="true"` to `remove="false"` ( or you can delete that line entirely ).